# LINQ query to get objects in recursive way to prepare a collection of objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

In my database table thee are some data. Each object can have their parent object. But there can only be three level. Now I would like to prepare a LINQ query to get the objects in recursive way. I have prepared the below query. Can anyone suggest me how to improve this query.

```
public class TreeView
    {
        public TreeView()
        {
            Children = new List<TreeView>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        // children
        public List<TreeView> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

**LINQ Query**

```
public static void GetItems(List<TreeView> models)
        {
            int id = 10;

            var lists = (from mod in models
                         where mod.Id == id
                         select new TreeView
                         {
                             Id = mod.Id,
                             Name = mod.Name,
                             Address = mod.Address,
                             Children = (from child in models
                                         where child.ParentId == mod.Id
                                         select new TreeView
                                         {
                                             Id = child.Id,
                                             ParentId = mod.Id,
                                             Name = child.Name,
                                             Address = child.Address,
                                             Children = (from grand in models
                                                         where grand.Id == child.Id
                                                         select new TreeView
                                                         {
                                                             Id = grand.Id,
                                                             ParentId = child.Id,
                                                             Name = grand.Name,
                                                             Address = grand.Address
                                                         }).ToList()

                                         }).ToList()
                         });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not think there is a need for all these levels. By taking the first level to any other level, children will be fetched! Children = mod.Children

Comment: Make a recursive method to hand this for any level, you can then just drill down instead of specifying every level.  The code is also neater when done that way.

Maybe worth having a look at this for more ideas on how to solve your issue.

https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/19237868/get-all-children-to-one-list---recursive-csharp